# I'm using malloc and my program is crashing

Tags: c, malloc

Today I was messing around with malloc and integer pointer. The program is setup so it allocates a memory location to an integer pointer and then fills the memory location with bunch of integers like an array and then print all the integers. The problem is when ever it finishes running it crashes. And I suspect that malloc is causing the issue.

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){

    int *name,x;
    char y;
    name=malloc(sizeof(int));
    for(x=0;x<500;x++){
        name[x]=x;
    }
    for(x=0;x<500;x++){
        printf("%d ",name[x]);
    }

    scanf("%c",&y);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

please help.
Thanks!

Comment: I bet it isn't `malloc`, but rather `name[x] = ` ..

Comment: If on Linux, learn to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and to debug with `gdb` and `valgrind` (and sometimes also `strace` or `ltrace`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allocating memory to store only one `int`. What you need is:

name=malloc(500*sizeof(int));

Answer (score 8):

```
name = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

is the problem. That way you can store only one int in the array. Try

```
name = malloc(sizeof(int) * 500);
```

instead.

Comment: Then may I ask why is it printing all 500 integers? And is there any other way of going about doing this without a specific number in the malloc statement?

Comment: @Anj17 - a specific number in the malloc statement is *not* a good idea.  Look at my response below.

Comment: @Anj17 it's printing all the numbers because it invokes undefined behavior. UB doesn't mean it **must** crash, it means it **can crash and do anything else**. And no, you have to malloc exactly `sizeof(int) * num` bytes explicitly if you want to store `num` integers.

Comment: @Anj17: you're writing off the end of the array.  This can (and does) cause unpredictable behavior, including corrupting other objects, the stack, who knows what else.  Sounds like all goes well until `free`.

Comment: @paulsm4 you're using a *specific number* for mallocation :) You just make sure it's always the same as the number of items you want to store. There *is* a slight difference...

Comment: I was thinking about what if I don't know exactly how many integers I need to store. So I was testing to see if this could be done without explicitly stating a number. Is there any solutions?

Comment: @H2CO3 Can you please explain?

Comment: [(If you don't, you're still not lost :))](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/realloc.html)

Comment: But with realloc I still have to specify a number. Can I do this without specifying a number? Or there any way around it?

Comment: @Anj17 what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can't allocate 'some' or 'enough' memory, you can allocate '10 bytes', or 'enough for storing 128 ints'... Your design probably needs revising if you can't solve this.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am trying to achieve storing x amount of integers in an array where x could be any number not known while developing the program.

Comment: But x is not know. I was trying to say that x could be anything. Essentially I am trying to define an array without any particular size as I could in Java.

Comment: @Anj17 Nevermind it's not known! (And don't accuse me of not understaing your language!) The point of malloc is that you don't have to know how many bytes you want to allocate. **Type and compile what I wrote. Only complain if it didn't work.**

Comment: I never said it didn't work in fact I am not accusing you of anything. I am sorry if I sounded like that. I didn't mean any offense. You said  that I don't have to know the number of bytes I want to allocate. But isn't 500*sizeof(int) trying to define it with a particular size?

Comment: @Anj17 yes it is. But you can have an `x` variable whose value is only known at runtime, then malloc `sizeof(int) * x` bytes. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What if the user doesn't know what x needs to be? what if the x is not know while runtime either?

Comment: @Anj17 then there are problems. You still haven't answered what all this is gonna be used for.

Comment: This is just an experiment. I remember not having to specify a size when defining arrays in java and thought maybe I could do something like that in c but that obviously doesn't work. So I was trying to find a way of indirectly doing it.

Comment: @Anj17 without context, sorry, I can't help. But I can provide you with an example sokution for a typical problem: reading an unspecified number of lines from stdin. Then you would put the reading code in a while loop, and reallocate upon each iteration.

Comment: That example problem will be helpful. Can you show me where is it?

Comment: @Anj17 it was the second half of my previous comment.

Comment: Oh ok. Umm can you maybe code it and post it as an answer here I am not understanding with just words. Thank you.

Comment: @Anj not now, sorry, it's 11pm here, I'm tired and it's long. Please make some effort to understand this, it's not that complicated. Every time the user enetrs a new line, you realloc your array to hold another string, like `arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(char *) * counter++)`, etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. That made sense. I think I can implement that.

Comment: @Anj17 of course you can :) Don't be afraid, you're good, just need a little more experience.

Answer (score 4):

Uh, "malloc()" isn't crashing your program.

*You're* crashing your program :)

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Check for "name=malloc()" returning NULL (i.e. check for errors).
2. Don't allocate space for *1* int ("sizeof(int)" is probably four bytes), then try to write *500* ints :)
3. Don't litter your code with "magic numbers" like "500" - use a constant instead.

SUGGESTED CHANGES:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NELMS 500

int main(){

    int *name = NULL,x;
    char y;
    name=malloc(sizeof(int) * NELMS);
    if (!name) {
      perror ("Unable to allocate memory!");
      return 1;
    }
    for(x=0;x<NELMS;x++){
        name[x]=x;
    }
    for(x=0;x<NELMS;x++){
        printf("%d ",name[x]);
    }

    scanf("%c",&y);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, checking the return of malloc is very important. Some times no memory may be available, or malloc cannot get to it for some reason.

Comment: Actually, not OP is crashing the program, but rather the kernel :)

Comment: Q: Isn't that a bit like saying your bumper caused the crash if you steer into a brick wall and floor the accelerator?  Just askin' ;)